# Background image JFrame with content

Tags: java, swing, jframe, background-image, border-layout

I have a `JFrame` with `BorderLayout`, there are panels on all sides (North, East ,...). In the panels there are labels and buttons mostly.

Now I want the frame to have a background image, some research told me that i had to change the content pane of my frame.

When I try this however, the content gets put in the background and isn't visible. Also, I don't know how to resize the image if the frame is resized.

Is there an easy fix for this or will I have to rework most of my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. put `JPanel` (or `JComponent`) with background Image to the `BorderLayout.CENTER`, then this `JPanel` fills whole `JFrame` area, rest of yout `JComponents` put to this `JPanel`
2. `there are Jpanels on all sides (North, East ,...). In the Jpanels there are Jlabels and Jbuttons mostly.`

   these `JComponents` covered all available `Rectangle` for `JFrame`, then `Background Image` (from my 1st point) never will be dispalyed, because these `JComponents` are on_top `JFrame` and could be hide this `Image` as well,
3. add `JPanel with Background Image` (from my 1st point), then put there another `JPanel(s)` with `JPanel#setOpaque(false);`, then this `JPanel` will be transparent, notice `JPanel` has implemented by default `FlowLayout`

Comment: `GridLayout()` and the `CENTER` of `BorderLayout` work very similarly.

Answer (score 1):

```
frame.getContentPane().add(new JPanel() {

      public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
      }
});
```

Comment: beware: a) this is a valid overrided only if the image is not transparent anywhere. b) adding to the contentPane does not fulfil the requirement of being below everything added :-)

Answer (score 0):

This example will get you started.  Use it like any JPanel.

```
public class JPanelWithBackground extends JPanel {
Image imageOrg = null;
Image image = null;
{
    addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            int w = JPanelWithBackground.this.getWidth();
            int h = JPanelWithBackground.this.getHeight();
            image = w>0&&h>0?imageOrg.getScaledInstance(w,h, 
                    java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH):imageOrg;
            JPanelWithBackground.this.repaint();
        }
    });
}
public JPanelWithBackground(Image i) {
    imageOrg=i;
    image=i;
    setOpaque(false);
}
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    if (image!=null) g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    super.paint(g);
}
}
```

Usage Example:

```
    Image image = your image
    JFrame f = new JFrame("");
    JPanel j = new JPanelWithBackground(image);
    j.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    j.add(new JButton("YoYo"));
    j.add(new JButton("MaMa"));
    f.add(j);
    f.setVisible(true);
```