# How to set an image for the panel background with seesaw?

Tags: image, user-interface, background, clojure, seesaw

I want to set a custom image for the panel background in my clojure app. Using seesaw I can set some color for the background:

```
(defn make-panel []
      (border-panel
        :north (flow-panel :align :center
                           :items [(label :text "TEXT")])
        :center (canvas :class :board
                        :background :black)
        :border 5))
```

but how to choose an image using its url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seesaw lets you use an image for `frame` content, via the [`icon` function](http://daveray.github.io/seesaw/seesaw.icon-api.html#seesaw.icon/icon) (now in `seesaw.icon`), like so:

```
(frame :title "Hola!"
       ; ....
       :content (label :icon img_bg)
```

where `img_bg` is a `File`, `URL`, etc.  However, looking at the Seesaw code, I don't see a way to put a background image directly in a panel through the Seesaw API.  You may have to drop down to Java interop and use the Swing API directly.  [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816079/background-image-jframe-with-content) would suggest that it's possible, and may get you started.